# pydrake: builder.Connect() fails with "Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type"

Tags: python, drake

I am trying something like the following (using [drake@00cdef03](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/00cdef03))

*Note*: This is not proper idiomatic Drake; you should declare a separate subclass when making a novel `LeafSystem`. This post just shows a compact, but hacky, form.

```py
from pydrake.all import (
    AbstractValue,
    DiagramBuilder,
    LeafSystem,
    SpatialForce,
    Value,
)

def fake_calc(context, output):
    raise NotImplemented()

producer = LeafSystem()
producer.DeclareAbstractOutputPort("output", alloc=SpatialForce, calc=fake_calc)
consumer = LeafSystem()
consumer.DeclareAbstractInputPort("input", model_value=AbstractValue.Make(SpatialForce()))

builder = DiagramBuilder()
builder.AddSystem(producer)
builder.AddSystem(consumer)
builder.Connect(producer.get_output_port(), consumer.get_input_port())
```

For some reason, it fails on `builder.Connect(...)` with the following error:

```
Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type (compile in debug mode for details)
```

If I print the value of the ports, they seem like the match the signature of the function:

```py
>>> producer.get_output_port()
<pydrake.systems.framework.LeafOutputPort_[float] object at 0x7febb5dba930>
>>> consumer.get_input_port()
<pydrake.systems.framework.InputPort_[float] object at 0x7febb5ff0930>
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in the fact that `alloc=SpatialForce` is being used, but it should be should be `alloc=Value[SpatialForce]`.

The following shows the difference between `good` and `bad`:

```py
system = LeafSystem()
# Good!
good = system.DeclareAbstractOutputPort("good", alloc=Value[SpatialForce], calc=fake_calc)
good.Allocate()

# BAD!
bad = system.DeclareAbstractOutputPort("bad", alloc=SpatialForce, calc=fake_calc)
bad.Allocate()  # Fails here
```

---

This happens because `alloc` must produce an instance of `AbstractValue`, which is used by `OutputPort::Alocate()` (in C++), which uses this `std::function<>` type: 
[`drake/.../value_producer.h`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/00cdef03991677cd987362ad70fd1976d113ae6a/systems/framework/value_producer.h#L52-L55)

It happens during `.Connect()` because that will ultimately call `Allocate()`: 
[`drake/.../diagram_builder.cc`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/00cdef03991677cd987362ad70fd1976d113ae6a/systems/framework/diagram_builder.cc#L112)

Because Python returns something not of an `AbstractValue` type, it is unable to cast, hence the error message